# HELP: Which version is correct: "It wasn't they who had changed the rules" or "It wasn't them who had changed the rules"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Which version is correct: "It wasn't they who had changed the rules" or "It wasn't them who had changed the rules"?

Answer (score 1):

'They' and 'them' are both pronouns, used in place of nouns or noun groups. 'They' and 'them' are always used in place of plural nouns or noun groups in the third person. The difference in grammatical terms is that 'they' is a subject pronoun, and 'them' is an object pronoun.

Any easy way to clarify this confusing situation (they vs. them) is to pare down the sentance to its basic meaning:

- It wasn't they who had changed the rules.

  - Drop *who had changed the rules*

    - It wasn't they.
- It wasn't them who had changed the rules

  - Drop *who had changed the rules*

    - It wasn't them.

Now it's easy to see that the correct usage is 'them.' This is because 'them' is used to refer to an object of a clause. In this case, 'it' is the subject, and 'them' refers to the unknown object. The object could be 'the rules committee,' or the 'home team,' or basically anyone who would normally be expected to change the rules, or who had been accused of changing the rules.

If we want to use 'they' to say the same thing, you would use it as the subject:

- They did not change the rules.

This takes it out of the past perfect tense. If what you want is to retain just the *past* tense you would say:

- They were not the ones who changed the rules.

If what you want is to retain the *past perfect* tense you would say:

- They were not the ones who had changed the rules.

Here's a helpful link: [One Stop English - they vs. them](http://www.onestopenglish.com/methodology/teaching-tips/ask-the-experts/grammar-questions/grammar-them-and-they/146352.article)

Comment: Doesn't the sentence need a comma? -- *It wasn't them, who had changed the rules.*

Comment: No, there's no real reason to add a comma there. If it's to indicate a pause for breathe or tempo, a comma is a confusing addition. If it's intended for emphasis, a better way would be to use formatting like italics. In either case it would be best to completely rewrite the sentence to read, "It wasn't them: they didn't change the rules."

Answer (score 0):

The version with "they" is correct. One can say "It wasn't them." in a short sentence, but that would be in a conversational register. The careful structure of the rest of the sentence really demands "they" as the subject of the clause.